# Azure function Service bus Queue Trigger - Message header

Tags: azure, azure-functions, message-queue, azureservicebus

I have created an Azure function that's triggered by the ServiceBus Queue.

> .Net 7 Isolated and Service Bus Queue Trigger

For the message datatype, if I use the "string" data type I can able to process the message in the Function App.

But If I change the type to ServiceBusReceivedMessage it throws an exception. I need to retrieve some information from the header. The actual message is a simple JSON query parameter.

Just logging throws an error.

```
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "connectionString")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
        _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
        _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: 1. Share your code w/o omitting important information, such as attributes. 2. What SDK and versions are you using? Most likely, you're not using the right/up-to-date packages.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer SDK version is the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`csproj:`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`Function.cs:`**

```
using System;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp76
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("rithwik", Connection = "rithwikcon")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
        }
    }
}
```

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "rithwikcon": "Endpoint=sb://rithwik8989.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=ZWQ2pBE="

  }
}
```

**`Output:`**

Sending json and string message both worked for me:

[image]

If still this does not work, i would suggest you to raise a support request as the code and process i am doing is right.

Comment: Thanks for the complete code. SDK version is the issue. Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk I had was 1.10. Once I updated that, It's working.

Comment: @Apsar, Glad it worked for you!